# Graph API send email using Powershell with & symbol in html body

Tags: powershell, api, email, graph, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to send graph API email with html body has an href URL which has & symbol in it.

Tried encoding & as %26 and email received with %26 in it and when clicked on it throws 404 error.

Tried changing the content type to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" but then it's not triggering the email.

sample code:

I have $toJsonAddress as an array.

```
$htmlhead="<html>
<style>
    body {
        font-family: 'verdana';font-size: 16px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-family: 'verdana';font-size: 18px;color: grey;
    }
    h2 {
        font-family: 'verdana';font-size: 18px;color: #2596be;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family: 'verdana';font-size: 16px;color: black;
    }
</style>"
#Header for the message
$HtmlBody = "<body>
<h1>test</h1>
<p>request <a href=""https://www.somedomain/help?id=sc_cat_item&amp;sys_id=12345"">here.</a></p>
"
$content = "</body></html>" + $HtmlHead + $HtmlBody | ConvertTo-Json
Write-Output "content is -->> $content"

$URLsend = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$MailSender/sendMail"
$BodyJsonsend = @"
                    {
                        "message": {
                          "subject": "$mailSubject",
                          "body": {
                            "contentType": "HTML",
                            "content": "$content "
                          },
                          "toRecipients": [
                          $toJsonAddress
                          ]
                        },
                        "saveToSentItems": "false"
                      }
"@

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URLsend -Headers $headers -Body $BodyJsonsend -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

JSON is converted and printed and received below error:

```
content is -->> "</body></html><html>\r\n<style>\r\n\tbody {\r\n\t\tfont-family: 'verdana';font-size: 16px;\r\n\t}\r\n\th1 {\r\n\t\tfont-family: 'verdana';font-size: 18px;color: grey;\r\n\t}\r\n\th2 {\r\n\t\tfont-family: 'verdana';font-size: 18px;color: #2596be;\r\n\t}\r\n\th3 {\r\n\t\tfont-family: 'verdana';font-size: 16px;color: black;\r\n\t}\r\n</style><body>\r\n     <h1>test</h1>\r\n<p>request <a href=\"https://www.somedomain/help?id=sc_cat_item&amp;sys_id=12345\">here.</a></p>\r\n"
Invoke-RestMethod: C:\Temp\imf4ah0e.3rb\fbb14734-21b4-4a83-a2ea-c774b3f7045a.ps1:67
Line |
  67 |  Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URLsend -Headers $headers -Body  …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | {"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"A supported MIME type
     | could not be found that matches the content type of the response. None
     | of the supported type(s) 'Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType, Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaType,
     | Microsoft.OData.ODataMediaTyp...' matches the content type
     | 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'."
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the character for the ampersand `&amp;` instead of `&`.

Also the URL in `href` attribute should be in double quotes

```
$HTMLBody = "<html><body><p>Portal: <a href=""https://sampledns/overview?ff=abc&amp;ln=xyz"">some text</a></p></body></html>"
```

Comment: It has some styles to be applied so html body needs to closed in double quotes like ```<style>
 body {
  font-family: 'verdana';font-size: 16px;
 }
 h1 {
  font-family: 'verdana';font-size: 18px;color: grey;  }
</style>
'```

Comment: @TechSavvy8102 could you update your code? So we can check what exactly is in $HTMLBody. If you need to use double quotes you can use double the quotation marks around a double-quoted phrase. See updated answer

Comment: Updated the post. Before passing the content to API converted html code to JSON still it errors out. It is missing required MIME data type and I'm not sure what is expected. Using "&" in email content is challenging now. I have also tried changing content-type to text/html, applicaton/json

Comment: @TechSavvy8102 The content type should be `application/json`: `Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URLsend -Headers $headers -Body $BodyJsonsend -ContentType "application/json"`

Comment: Yes tried as application/json but received below error ``` Invoke-RestMethod: C:\3f7045a.ps1:67
Line |
  67 |  Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $URLsend -Headers $headers -Body  …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Unable to read JSON request
     | payload. Please ensure Content-Type header is set and payload is of
     | valid JSON
     | format.","innerError":{"date":"2023-01-18T07:55:22","request-id":"46256b04-a6e6-4955-be01-734c2f221b","client-request-id":"4-4955-be01-734c2fef221b"}}}  ```

Comment: @TechSavvy8102 If you try to print $BodyJsonsend what does it print? How do you create $toJsonAddress?

Comment: "toRecipients": [
  {
    "emailAddress": {
   "address": "someaddress@somedomain.com"
    }
  }
   ]